# Load random file from directory

Tags: node.js, random

So i'm building a game and i want to choose a random file from a directory as a map. I found this old topic which gave the answer

```js
const randomFile = require('random-file')

const dir = '/tmp/whatever'
randomFile(dir, (err, file) => {
  console.log(`The random file is: ${file}.`)
})
```

but it seems that fs is no longer in use, but fs.realpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

fs.readdir(path.join(process.cwd(), "maps"), (err, files) => {

    console.log(err, files)

    let max = files.length - 1;
    let min = 0;

    let index = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    let file = files[index];

    console.log("Random file is", file);

});
```

In less then 20 lines.
Why do people use for every simple task a external module?!

Regardless that the package does not what you want...